# Azure AD: revoke authorization code?

Tags: adal

say a client persists the authz code token and now you need to manually revoke this token. 
where in the Azure AD portal, where can I revoke an authorization code grant token ?

regards Allan

Comment: Confidential client (e.g. WebApp or WebAPI), or public client (e.g. native client app, phone app, SPA)?

Comment: @Allan Nielsen - please revise the question if it relates to access/refresh token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authorization code is single use. There is no revocation for it, however it is valid for a very short time -if not redeemed right away, it won't work.

The access token it itself cannot be revoked - the consumer does not consult AAD to validate it. However it has a relatively short validity (today is 1 hour) and as soon as it expires it must be refreshed with a refresh token.

The refresh token can be invalidated (hence making impossible to derive new access tokens form it) by changing the user's password. Note that this does not work for microsoft accounts (MSA) guest users.

HTH
V.

Comment: Refresh token right, my mistake. I was hoping/thinking more in the line of the functionality provided in thinktecture identity server, where you can see a list of refresh tokens scoped to a client id and then delete them. That part is not done well (IMO) in AAD today. okay thank you :). cheers Allan

Comment: Exception code triggered by an expired Azure AD authorization code:

(invalid_grant) AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS70008: The provided access grant is expired or revoked.
Trace ID: dec5a365-38ee-47a0-825d-55683d00c293
Correlation ID: 70745923-a025-478d-805a-430720cf85e8
Timestamp: 2015-03-13 09:22:05Z